# how to move the text to the left?

Tags: java, swt

I created a toolbar with text field and two toolItem

The problem that the Text is exist in the right scrren and not in the left screen.

How I can put the text in the right screen ?

It should look :

Text   item1   item2

```
   ToolBar treeToolBar = new ToolBar(treeComposite, SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);


    Text text = new Text(treeToolBar, SWT.NONE);
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.LEFT, false, false));
    text.setText("Text"); 
    text.pack();

    item1 = new ToolItem(treeToolBar, SWT.PUSH | SWT.RIGHT);

    item2 = new ToolItem(treeToolBar, SWT.PUSH | SWT.RIGHT);


   treeToolBar.pack();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the text, you also have to create a tab item for it. Remove the `text.pack()` call and insert this:

```
ToolItem textItem = new ToolItem(treeToolBar, SWT.SEPARATOR);
textItem.setControl(text);
textItem.setWidth(text.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, true).x);
```

This is how `ControlContribution` does in method `fill(ToolBar parent, int index)`.

Comment: Thansk is work but now I want that the text will be in the left screen without any space to the left

Comment: @user1365697 you set the `SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT` flag to the toolbar. If you want it on the left, replace it with `SWT.NONE`.